# NSMutableArray addObjects Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am adding array to my `NSMutableArray` but it crashed.
Here is my code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (data.length >0 && connectionError ==nil) {
        NSDictionary *myData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];


        self.currWeather = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.weatherIconUrl =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.currWeather = myData[@"data"][@"current_condition"][0][@"weatherIconUrl"];
        self.weather = [[myData objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"weather"];


        self.weatherIconUrl = [self.weather valueForKeyPath:@"weatherIconUrl"];

        [self.weatherIconUrl addObjectsFromArray:self.currWeather]; //here is the problem
        NSLog(@"the url is %@",self.weatherIconUrl);
    }
}];
```

I tried to change "currWeather" from `NSMutable` to `NSArray` but it failed again.

Here is the error:

```
-[__NSArrayI addObjectsFromArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x908e3a0
2014-05-15 16:21:58.376 myRestSample[2239:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObjectsFromArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x908e3a0'
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: You're trying to modify an immutable NSArray (as the exception clearly states).

Comment: Your array is an `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @HotLicks That duplicate has a similar error but the answer has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @rmaddy - Then pick a better one -- there are probably thousands.

Comment: Or it's just off-topic as a simple typographical error even.  Please learn to read your exceptions... don't just copy & paste them to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `self.weatherIconUrl` is just an an immutable NSArray and not an NSMutableArray.

```
//Assuming weatherIconUrl is declared as an NSMutableArray, you could try this:
self.weatherIconUrl = [[self.weather valueForKeyPath:@"weatherIconUrl"]mutableCopy];
```

Comment: oh God,You are right. can you tell me more about that "mutableCopy"?

Comment: @TianMing If I'm not mistaken, it's the equivalent of `self.weatherIconUrl = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.weather valueForKeyPath:@"weatherIconUrl"]];`